# Setting up local Minecraft for multiple player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

My home setup is like this: We have 2 laptops connected wirelessly, 1 laptop connected wired, and 1 desktop connected wired.  All are connected to the internet via a wireless router.  What we want to do is be able to have the desktop computer "host" the Minecraft "server" and allow the other three laptops access it.  Does anyone have instructions on how I set this up?

Answer (score 3):

When you are in-game you can either use the `/publish` command or use the "Open to LAN" button in the menu

> To open your current single player world for other players in your LAN, type the command `/publish` into the chat (note that this is still very restricted, e.g. you can't adjust the game options using the commandline) or access the Game Menu and click on the "Open to LAN" button. There you can select the gamemode for other players and whether they should be allowed to use Cheats. Both of these methods give you an IP for use, for example: "Local game hosted on hostname:12345". If you type `/publish` and want to change the default gamemode, type `/defaultgamemode 1` for example. Note: two computers using the same Minecraft account name cannot connect with this method.
>
> Now other players can either connect to your game using the link minecraft provided you or they can connect using the multiplayer menu with its new "Scanning for LAN-Worlds" section at the bottom.

Soruce: [Multiplayer - Local area network](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lan_server#Local_area_network)

So to elaborate, on the Desktop Computer you would start up Minecraft, go into the world you're going to host and do what it says in the quote. the Laptops should then be able to use either the link you got or the Multiplayer Menu

Comment: So do i have to install just the local version of Minecraft on the desktop computer or do i install the Server version of MInecraft on the desktop...

Comment: @TomCusick If you're just doing a local game with friends or family at your house, then you just need to download Minecraft, and start your world. When you go in the start menu, it will display a button saying "Open to LAN" Click on that button, and it will say 'Local game hosted on port (port number)'. Also, there is no 'Server version' of Minecraft, there is a Minecraft server jar you can download if you want to host a server for other people not on your internet connection.

Comment: If your LAN won't work (it won't detect the server), you can also always use Hamachi to establish LAN via internet...this way also people form outside can connect, if you let them to connect to your Hamachi network

Comment: Ok so i started the LAN game on the Desktop computer and it tells me "Local game hosted on port 60715".

But when i go to the laptop and startup minecraft (same version 1.8.4)  and select Multiplayer game the Scanning for games on your local network just appears to be searching and not finding anything...

Answer (score 0):

In reply at the comment:

> Ok so i started the LAN game on the Desktop computer and it tells me "Local game hosted on port 60715". But when i go to the laptop and startup minecraft (same version 1.8.4) and select Multiplayer game the Scanning for games on your local network just appears to be searching and not finding anything...

I've also had the same problem.

I solved the problem going to set the rules in the firewall.

Go into your firewall. "Windows Firewall" Then click the tab "Allow a program or feature through Windows Firewall" In here, scroll down to Java(TM) Platform SE binary. You may have 1 or more of them. Set all of them to public and then your friend will be able to join with your firewall still on. That's how I did it. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok so here is what i tried. I disabled all firewall options.Running Windows 7 on all my machines. Would this make a difference?

Started Minecraft on the desktop.  Enabled Lan World.

On laptop, Play Multiplayer, Add server, put in IP with the Port on it. Then refreshed on the laptop and I see the "Server" but when i attempt to connect it tells me:

Failed to connect to the server
Failed to login: Invalid Session (try restarting your game)

Which i have done multiple times, even restarted both computers...

I get the same error message when trying a direct connection.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Do i have to setup port forwarding or port triggering on my router for the minecraft to be accessed?? is there a way to hardcode the port i want to use for Minecraft?  i've noticed that everytime i restart it and enable the Lan World it gives me a new port number.

Answer (score 0):

You must own copy of minecraft each. You can't play together using the same account. To do that you'd need to use the minecraft server instead and set it to offline mode.

Comment: is it difficult to set up a minecraft server for my local networking?